# [SPApplication _accessibilityInitialize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance on watchOS4

Tags: swift, beta, xcode9-beta, watchos-4

Once my watch app starts, it crashes with the following error:

`2017-08-17 13:59:54.304792-0300 watchOS4 Extension[11500:1617313] -[SPApplication _accessibilityInitialize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79e5b8f0
2017-08-17 13:59:56.173675-0300 watchOS4 Extension[11500:1617313] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SPApplication _accessibilityInitialize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79e5b8f0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x015ae80d __exceptionPreprocess + 189
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f22bcf objc_exception_throw + 49
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0162f978 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 136
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x015322c4 ___forwarding___ + 1300
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01531d8e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   UIAccessibility                     0x19a13e2c __54+[UIAccessibilityLoader _accessibilityLoadSubbundles:]_block_invoke.338 + 44
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x05f990bf _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x05f9a42c _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x05fa4e88 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1204
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0157116e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0153677e __CFRunLoopRun + 3310
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x015357e5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 373
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0153565a CFRunLoopRunInMode + 122
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x08fde249 GSEventRunModal + 71
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x08fde12e GSEventRun + 80
    15  UIKit                               0x01a402d1 UIApplicationMain + 148
    16  libxpc.dylib                        0x06350a67 _xpc_objc_main + 528
    17  libxpc.dylib                        0x063533a0 xpc_main + 158
    18  Foundation                          0x009543c5 -[NSXPCListener resume] + 185
    19  PlugInKit                           0x057be28b -[PKService run] + 799
    20  WatchKit                            0x001cd123 main + 160
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x05ffdd41 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

What does the **SPApplication _accessibilityInitialize** means? I do not implement any accessibility functionality yet.

Im running watchOS4 beta 6 and XCode 9 beta 5

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For who else experiencing this problem: just restart Xcode and simulators and perform a Clean in the project. Worked for me.

Comment: I think the "restart Xcode" is the most important part

Comment: Resetting the simulators fixed for me

Comment: (1) restart Xcode -> Clean
(2) restart Simulators 
(3) Build 
It works well. Thanks

Comment: @Lewis42 Done. Thanks for remembering me :)